# Can I replace var root = this

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

with

```
var root = window || exports;
```

If I assume the code will only run in a browser or Node environment?

Here is an example of a use case

http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-4

but this actually for my own library

Comment: Sure you can.  But it might not be correct.  There's no way to know, the question doesn't contain enough context.

Comment: No, accessing window will throw a ReferenceError on node.

Comment: No, `exports` is not the same as `this`. You can use  `var root = typeof window != "undefined" ? window : global`, but why not simply stick with `this`?

Comment: @Bergi - ask jslint / crockford that ... ? ...  I guess this is "dangerous" to use.

Comment: @brannon Crockford considers a lot of things "dangerous" that aren't. If you can't find a good argument yourself, you just should use it.

Comment: @Bergi - better yet, if he can't document why on his own web site, then it's just a poor tool to use.